# Embed SVG into PDF programmatically in .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, svg

Does anyone know how to create a pdf with C# and add a SVG document inside of this PDF ?

itextsharp can't do it.

I convert SVG into image thanks to this library (http://svg.codeplex.com/) but I need to keep vectorial graphic because image is pixelised.

Anyone know a library to do it ?

Thanks,

Comment: is it possible with itextsharp.
 `MyImageStream = new MemoryStream();
myChart.SaveImage(MyImageStream);`  

my chart would be the svg chart object

Comment: I changed the way to do this. I convert svg in emf and generate a docx. But so with this solution when you zoom on the image it's not pixelize? If it's not pixelize propose it as solution. But I can't test anymore cz I changed all my code.

Answer (score 3):

PrinceXML does a very good job of handling SVG, however, it is not completely free, meaning that the free version puts a small logo on the output PDF. You can find out more here: http://www.princexml.com/doc/7.0/svg/

PDFJet will allow you to create lines, circles, polygons, and other primitive drawing tools. You could create a class to parse your SVG and then draw the appropriate circles, arcs, lines, etc and use PDFJet to make the PDF. PDFJet can be downloaded here: http://pdfjet.com/os/edition.html

Other then that, I don't think there are many other options for what you are looking to do.

Comment: The second solution is very complicate. The first one is nice but I can't accept a logo.

Comment: @Dragouf - Actually, there is a SVG library here: [An SVG Framework in C# and an SVG-GDI+ bridge](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/svgnet.aspx) You could use this library to parse the SVG, then use PDFJet or even iTextSharp to draw the poly, line and arc primitives.

Comment: It seems its a long coding and I don't have enought time. But it seems pdf can embed svg xobject if I well understand. For me moment I use to convert svg with inkscape command line and then merge pdf with itextsharp. But I can't position the resulting object correctly on the page... :s

Answer (score 2):

[PDFKit.NET3](http://www.tallcomponents.com/pdfkit3-features.aspx) can insert the SVG document into PDF, while preserving vectors.

Answer (score 1):

[webSupergoo ABCpdf](http://www.abcpdf.com/products.htm) is also a good commercial option, a bit less pricey (ABCpdf Std costs $329, and ABCpdf Pro cost $479 if you want rendering or x64 support). Version 7 did a terrible job when handling SVG files (it could only load a small subset, often with issues), but I understand (haven't test it first hand) that version 8 (and now 9) greatly improved its SVG support by switching to the [Gecko engine](http://www.abcpdf.com/helppdf9net/source/5-abcpdf/xhtmloptions/2-properties/1-engine.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately it has terrible support for Azure... They state on their website that one has to set up a virtual machine. I'm trying to migrate a solution using `ABCpdf` to Azure Web App and this library is currently is the only obstacle...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the past it was not possible but now, using `iText7` it is.

Notice that you will need to install `itext7.bouncy-castle-fips-adapter` and `itext7.font-asian` in order to work.

I also use `PDFSharp` for merging the pdfs because I was doing some modifications on each page but you could merge them using iText7 anyway.

My SVGs are in a folder, if you need to modify anything, go ahead!

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using iText.Svg.Converter;
using iText.Layout.Font;
using iText.Svg.Processors.Impl;

Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

var document = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument();

string tempPDF = "temp.pdf";

var list = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.svg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

for (int ev = 0; ev < list.Length; ev++)
{
    FontProvider provider = new FontProvider();

    SvgConverterProperties props = new SvgConverterProperties();
    props.SetCharset("Windows-1252");
    props.SetFontProvider(provider);

    FileStream svgPath = File.Open(list[ev], FileMode.Open);
    FileStream pdfPath = File.Create(tempPDF);
    SvgConverter.CreatePdf(svgPath, pdfPath, props);

    PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(tempPDF, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

    document.AddPage(inputDocument.Pages[0]);

}
File.Delete(tempPDF);

string fileName = path + "/output.pdf";

// Save and start View
document.Save(fileName);
```

Sometimes the output is not 100% correct but the result is pretty decent, I am trying to get throught and if I find a better solution, I let you know!