# PDF creator using AngularJS or C#

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, pdf, svg

I need to generate a PDF using either C# or JavaScript (I am using AngularJS as the front end), but there is a complication. The "page" that I need to generate has a few SVG images on it that need to be converted also.

I did find this plugin:

http://pdfkit.org/

but that doesn't appear to allow me to add multiple SVGs to a PDF. Also, it isn't an AngularJS library so I would have to create my own directive.

Does anyone know of any alternatives or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm ussually using PdfSharp for generating PDFs - It is a NuGet package, so using is strait-forward. But according to this forum: http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2612 svg is supported, but it crashes, when used. - But the information is 2 years old. I thing that it is worth a try.

I have also found another alternative here on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6568523/4640779 using itextsharp.

Both described methods migth work with C#, surelly not javascript.

Comment: I will give them both a look and report back :)

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the contributors to CSS-to-PDF. http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf has many examples showing SVG charts to PDF and other formats. The sample page for Google Charts which are SVG is here:

http://www.cloudformatter.com/GoogleCharts

It is a Javascript/remote formatting server jQuery plugin. http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.APIDoc.Usage has use instructions. I have not had any issues with many different typs of SVG as long as you make sure they carry the proper SVG namespace.